# can I aggregate computing resources from multiple servers in a private cloud?

Tags: cloud, eucalyptus

It might be a naive question, but I have four servers (on the same network) which I want to utilize for running a computing intensive tool. The tool itself is not designed to be run in a distributed environment (a cluster). So if I use a private cloud solution (e.g. [Eucalyptus](https://www.eucalyptus.com/)), would I be able to make the four server "virtually" look like one and run the tool on that "virtual" big server?

If this is not the right approach, then what are the solutions that can aggregate resources from different servers.

Comment: But is it prepared to run concurrent tasks in separate threads?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGómez .. I don't have access to information about how the tool is implemented.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's not such magical tool which can combine computers as if they were only one, since physical limitations, where a CPU has one isolated cache memory for example, and you can't share it with other one to run the same program, and like that a lot of other problems. If it could be ran on multiple threads, that would be a different history.

Answer (score 0):

To add with [Álvaro Gómez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4435723/%C3%81lvaro-g%C3%B3mez), I think you can also look into various implementations of [Grid computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing). Private cloud platforms which provides Infrastructure-as-a-Service (IaaS) platform e.g Eucalyptus, Openstack generally serves a completely purpose where basically you won't be able to use more compute resources for a  than the physical nodes itself.